# Select data from mssql using excel vba and where statement

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I need select data from database, using Excel. I want to select only one column from database and I need use `where` statement (to select only data which have the same unique value as data in Excel sheet)

I tried this

```
    Sub DB_RTVresult()
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String

    Dim myRes As ADODB.Recordset
    Server_Name = "123" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "DBName" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "UserName" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "Pass" ' Enter your password here

    Set myCon = New ADODB.Connection

Worksheets(2).Select
LastRow = GetRowCnt
For bl = LastRow To 5 Step -1
myCon.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"
myCon.Open
     SQLStr = "SELECT [RTV_RESULT]" & _
  "FROM [WSCZWMS].[WSCZWMS].[OMEGA_E2E_REPORT] WHERE [SME_TRACK_NO] ='" & Cells(bl, "CC").Value & "'"
    Set myRes = myCon.Execute(SQLStr)

   Worksheets("HelpTables").Range("E2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset (1)
    StrQuery = "OMEGA_SPEQ_REPORT"

myCon.Close

Set myRes = Nothing
Set myCon = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

But when I run it, it writes Application-define or object-define error.
and colored this line

```
Worksheets("HelpTables").Range("E2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset myRes
```

This line dave the select data into first empty row in column E, (start on 3rd row)

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issue is, that you are already referring to the Row in your `.Range("E2" & Rows.Count)` .

If you modify the mentioned line to the following, it should work properly:

```
Worksheets("HelpTables").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset myRes
```

The `5` in `.Cells(Rows.Count, 5)` is for the fifth column ('E').

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it seems that your excel objects Cells dans Rows should be affected and your sheets selected.

I would have writen

```
    For b1=...
        Worksheets(2).select
        ...
        ... Worksheets(2).cells(b1,"CC").value
        ...
        Worksheets("HelpTables").select
        Worksheets("HelpTables").Range("E" & _
           Worksheets("HelpTables").Range("E:E").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ...
        ...
```

NB :

"CC" is the name of a Excel value ?

Do you want Range("E2" & rows.count) to go to E2100 if there are 100 rows ? That's why I wrote "E" and not "E2" in my proposition. But may be you wanted (... rows.count+2) ?

Hope it helps.
Pierre.